# Openpyxl - getting error - no data is returned

Tags: openpyxl

Here's the code-

```
    wb   = load_workbook(filename, use_iterators=True)
    ws   = wb.worksheets[0]

 for row in range(1, 4):
     for col in range(32, 35):
        print 'Value = ', ws.cell(column=col, row=row, value="%s" %   get_column_letter(col))
```

The program's output is as follows-

```
 Value =  <Cell Data.AF1>
   Value =  <Cell Data.AG1>
   Value =  <Cell Data.AH1>
   Value =  <Cell Data.AF2>
```

How do I get the correct value?

I tried the following things-

```
print 'Value = ', ws.cell(row = 1, column = 1).value

O/P is Value =  None

print 'Value = ', ws['A1'].value

O/P is Value =  ExportDate (This is the correct value)
```

Comment: Hm to me it seems you've got the correct value already. So could do something like `for col in ['A','B','C']` and then `ws["{}{}".format.(col,row)].value` and it'll be grand. To get all the uppercase letters there are you can do this: `import string; string.ascii_uppercase`.

Comment: Thanks Aleksander, but could you explain me in details please. I want that the program should automatically iterate through the columns from 32 till max columns

Comment: while (all_cols < (ws.get_highest_column() - 3)):
    ColT                       = 0
    ColD                       = 0
    ColT                       = 32
    ColD                       = ColT     + 1
    cell_name_Target        = ws.cell(row = 1, column = ColT).value #Get Target name
    cell_name_Dis           = ws.cell(row = 1, column = ColD).value

Comment: Not sure what more to explain, frankly. Take the ASCII uppercase letters, generate a list with the names of the columns and substitute for my `['A','B','C']`. You can then use `[32:35]` to get the elements of the lists you want.

Comment: Which version of openpyxl and python are you using?

Comment: I don't use openpyxl, I tried it but now I just drive Excel through the COM ports, it's so much better and easier. I just figured out what would work from what you said you'd tried and worked. Hence didn't post it as an answer because I hadn't tested it. Python 2.7.5, if that matters ;)

Answer (score 0):

`ws.cell()` always returns a Cell object which is what you see in the print statements. The `.value` property returns the value of the cell. `ws.get_squared_range()` will allow you to get a range of cells from a worksheet. All this is covered in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks Charlie Clark. I modified to cell_name_Target  = ws(row = 1, column = ColT).value #Get Target name
But this returns me error - TypeError: 'IterableWorksheet' object is not callable

Comment: Which version of openpyxl and python are you using?

Comment: Please go through the tutorial in the documentation. Simply trying stuff out will not work. These methods haven't changed since version 2.0

Comment: Yes Charlie, I went through the documentation and did try exactly as written. Still then I'm getting an error - print 'Value = ', sheet.cell(row =1, column =1).value    This simple sentence is also printing None as output. Please help me.

Comment: Then the cell has no value.

Comment: print 'Value = ', sheet.cell(row =1, column =1).value -->This statement returns me None. 
print 'Value = ', sheet['A1'].value -->This print statement shows me value

Answer (score 0):

I might be misunderstanding your problem, but I think this is what you want:

1) Don't use `use_iterators`.  I think that's part of the problem.  Just do this:

```
wb   = load_workbook(filename)
ws   = wb.worksheets[0]
```

2) If you want the value, then you need to ask for it:

```
for row in range(1, 4):
    for col in range(32, 35):
        print 'Value = ', ws.cell(column=col, row=row).value
```

Comment: Thanks David. The use_iterators was the issue